# Flutter web state and server-side solutions with flutter

Tags: node.js, firebase, flutter, flutter-web, nodejs-server

What is the current state of flutter for web in performance, specially on mobile?
And can flutter run Nodejs code?
I am fairly new to web development and was looking for a quick solution to compile my flutter apps to Web.
I am using Firebase too, so not sure if I need Nodejs right now, but its good to know if flutter supports server side programming so if I changed the backend later.

Thanks!

Comment: Flutter supports network requests, so you can expose a Node.js backend on a public webserver and make requests to that server from Flutter. Flutter itself cannot run Node.js, since Node.js is a backend solution and Flutter is a frontend.

Comment: ok so is it okay to use it with firebase without any server side code?

Comment: ok so is it okay to use it with firebase without any server side code?